# Failed to load ido.el

Tags: ido

I have downloaded file `ido.el`, but can't load it.  When I `(require 'ido)` the following is displayed:

**Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "seq")
  require(seq)
  eval-buffer(# nil "/home/admin/.emacs.d/ido.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 13523
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/admin/.emacs.d/ido.el" "/home/admin/.emacs.d/ido.el" nil t)
  require(ido)
  eval((require (quote ido)) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)**

This is with *GNU Emacs 24.4.1*

Comment: /home/admin/.emacs.d
admin@linux:~/.emacs.d$ ls -l
итого 200
drwx------ 2 admin admin   4096 сен 29 15:31 auto-save-list
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin    208 сен 27 16:29 bookmarks
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 176224 сен 29 15:17 ido.el

Comment: It seems `ido` itself `(require 'seq)` but emacs can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Ido is part of Emacs since Emacs 22, you can (and should) load it without any setup. Emacs 24 can or can't load Emacs 25's `ido.el`. The backtrace complains: can't load `seq`. `seq` is added from Emacs 25.1. You can install `seq` on Emacs 24. However, if you want to use a newer version of Ido, I think you should use a newer version of Emacs.

Comment: All I'm there already figured out all works. But what is a seq?

Comment: @КириллФёдоров [seq](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/seq.html) is an Emacs Lisp package.